# Sublime Text 3 PHP Syntax Highlighting Issue

Tags: php, sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

Sublime Text 3 is set to PHP syntax but nesting causes some weird syntax highlighting issue as seen in the image below.

[image: weird syntax highlighting issue]

I was wondering if anyone else encountered this issue and if they solved it?

PS: I posted this on stackoverflow but people don't like it there. I was told to try superuser.

Comment: Looks like a bug. The ST issue tracker is on github see https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues.